# How to compare data from database in user defined formulas

Tags: php, mysql

I have database table with fields:

- pagerank
- sites_in_google_index
- conversion_rate
- sites_in_google_index
- adsense_revenue
- yahoo_backlins
- google_baclinks

and about 20 more parameteres - all are integers collected every day

Now I need to add user posibility to define own keys and virtualize this data on graphs, for example user can define sth like this:

```
NEW_KEY_1 = pagerank*google_backlinks-(conversion_rate+site_in_google_index)
```

and

```
NEW_KEY_2 = adsense_revenue*NEW_KEY_1
```

An now he should show this two data keys on graph for selected time period, ex: 01-12-2009 to 02-03-2011

What is the best strategy to store and evaluate such data/keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to allow users to define the SQL selector and use in the query to your database. However, **do not do this never ever** (!), since it is one of the biggest security wholes you can dig!

The general idea should be to provide some kind of "custom query language" to your users. You then need a parser to validate its expressions and create an abstract syntax tree out of it. This syntax tree can then be transformed to a corresponding SQL query part.

In your specific case, you will basically end up parsing arithmetic expressions, in order to validate that the user provided field only contains such expressions and that they are valid, and serialize the corresponding tree back to SQL arithmetic expressions. Other benefits here are that you can ensure only valid field names are used, that you can limit the complexity of expressions and that you can add custom operators at a later stage.